# Problems building DBD Sybase on Debian

Tags: c, linux, perl, gcc

I am trying to build DBD::Sybase on Debian machine, but I am running into a problem. The problem is, *`BFD (GNU Binutils) 2.21.1 internal error`* when linking the program. Please help me resolve this.

1. I successfully installed freetds
2. Downloaded "DBD-Sybase-1.16"
3. Executed "perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/usr/lib/perl5/" which was successfull
4. When I execute "sudo make", I get the following error. I tried googling but could not find help.

Here is the tail of the build.

```
Skip blib/lib/DBD/Sybase.pm (unchanged)   
Skip blib/lib/DBD/dbd-sybase.pod (unchanged)  
Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::Sybase ()   
chmod 644 Sybase.bs   
/network/glnxa64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/gcc -c  -I/usr/local/freetds/include -DSYB_LP64 -DNO_BLK=1 -I/company/hub/share/apps/BuildTools/Linux/glibc-2.13/x86_64/perl/perl-5.20.2-mw-021/lib/site_perl/5.20.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2 -pipe -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2   -DVERSION=\"1.16\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.16\" -fPIC "-I/company/hub/share/apps/BuildTools/Linux/glibc-2.13/x86_64/perl/perl-5.20.2-mw-021/lib/5.20.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   Sybase.c     

/network/glnxa64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/gcc -c  -I/usr/local/freetds/include -DSYB_LP64 -DNO_BLK=1 -I/company/hub/share/apps/BuildTools/Linux/glibc-2.13/x86_64/perl/perl-5.20.2-mw-021/lib/site_perl/5.20.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2 -pipe -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2   -DVERSION=\"1.16\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.16\" -fPIC "-I/company/hub/share/apps/BuildTools/Linux/glibc-2.13/x86_64/perl/perl-5.20.2-mw-021/lib/5.20.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   dbdimp.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/local/freetds/lib" /network/glnxa64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/gcc -shared   -L/usr/local/freetds/lib -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector Sybase.o dbdimp.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so       \
   -L/usr/local/freetds/lib -lct -ldl -lm       \

/network/glnxa64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/ld: BFD (GNU Binutils) 2.21.1 internal error, aborting at /local/greg/3p/sources/gcc-4.7/../binutils/bfd/reloc.c line 443 in bfd_get_reloc_size

/network/glnxa64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/ld: Please report this bug.

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:485: recipe for target 'blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so' failed
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Your gcc version is not the last one,perhaps you can try we a newer version

Comment: Thanks Orel. But my friend actually tried this on other Debian machine with same GCC version and it was successful. So I am not sure if GCC version is an issue here.

Comment: Why do you use `sudo make`? You run the configuration phase `perl ...` as normal user, but the compilation as root. Why?

Comment: [Binutils Bug 20562, Linker aborting on line 444 in bfd_get_reloc_size](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20562). It is an old Binutils, so it is unlikely to be fixed if it has not already been fixed. Given H.J. Lu's answer was *"Please try binutils 2.27"*, I'm guessing it will not be fixed.

Comment: Also, instead of `LD_RUN_PATH`, you might try linker options `-Wl,-rpath=<...>` and `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. It is just some knob turning that tries to work around something that may confuse the linker. It does not solve the underlying problem with the tool. And as Stefan said, use just `make` (and not `sudo make`). The only time to use `sudo` is during `sudo make install` when you need `root`.

Comment: rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/local/freetds/lib" /network//glnxa64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/gcc -shared   -L/usr/local/freetds/lib -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector Sybase.o dbdimp.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so       \
   -L/usr/local/freetds/lib -lct -ldl -lm \
/network//glnxa64/gcc-4.7.2/bin/ld: cannot open output file blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so: Permission denied
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:485: recipe for target 'blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so' failed
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so] Error 1

Comment: Above is an error I get when I use "make" instead of "sudo make"

Comment: If you have additional information please add it to the question. It is practically unreadable as a comment. You can add the additional information to the question by clicking *Edit*.

Comment: Well using a different version of binutils worked. I used version 2.28. The error message is not so obvious. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As @jww pointed out, the issue was the older version of binutils and gcc. I just edited the generated Makefile in Sybase base directory to point to newer versions of gcc and binutils. FYI, I the versions that worked are "gcc version 6.3.0 " and "GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.28.1"